# JsonNode.Parse: error parsing text with accents

Tags: c#, parsing, system.text.json, codepages, utf8json

I am trying to parse a Latin text with the Parse method of JsonNode from System.Text.Json class.

But when the text contains accents, the method returns escape characters.

```
var jsonString = File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));                   
var jTemplate = JsonNode.Parse(jsonString);
```

The object "*jsonString*" contain the right text (with accents) but when I call JsonNode.Parse the object "jTemplate" contains the bad text

> "Ciberseguridad en la organización" in jsonString
>
> "Ciberseguridad en la **organizaci\u00F3n**" in jTemplate

I have also tried other encoding and code page, for example **UTF8** with the same results...

¿Any idea how to parse text with accents?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

For the moment `JsonNode.Parse()` doesn't provide a way to set the `Encoder` [similar to JsonSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-character-encoding).

You have two options:

1. Use `JsonSerializer` instead and follow the tips from the link above.
2. Unescape the string value after parsing it using the `JsonNode`:

   ```cs
   var expectedValue = Regex.Unescape(jTemplate["key"].ToString());
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I can offer you to use JsonSerializer.Deserialize method which accept JsonSerializerOptions object where you can set Encoder.

The output of my code sample is:

> Ciberseguridad en la organización

```
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Unicode;

string jsonString = "{\"data\": \"Ciberseguridad en la organización\"}";
JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
{
    Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.Create(UnicodeRanges.All)
};
DataDto? jTemplate = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<DataDto>(jsonString, options);
Console.WriteLine(jTemplate.data);

class DataDto
{
    public string data { get; set; }
}
```